# Design rich text area in iPhone

Tags: iphone, xcode, textbox, richtextbox

I want to design a rich text area for iPhone where user can enter text or multiple images such that when user attached image it just come after the text ends and after that continue to write text.
When user edits the text the image will also get adjustable according to it.

Any suggestion how to achieve it.
Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

IOS 5.0 introduces editable UIWebView. This makes rich text editing in iphone less complicated.

Just go through these tutorial's series http://ios-blog.co.uk/iphone-development-tutorials/rich-text-editing-a-simple-start-part-1/

The best tutorials for rich text editing in IOS 5 !!!

Comment: Its good for rich text editing but in my case I want to attach image in text box also. When user edits the text then I also want to move the positions of image view corresponding to text.So I think this code might not be helpful for me. Thanks anyways for your effort.

Comment: yes you can insert image too in webview.. see tutorial-7 of this series

Answer (score 1):

Today, your best bet for this IMO is a `UIWebView`. You should start by watching Session 511 ("Rich Text Editing in Safari on IOS") from WWDC 2011. You may want to start with one of the existing JavaScript solutions with good Safari support, such as [TinyMCE](http://tinymce.moxiecode.com) or [CKEditor](http://ckeditor.com), and adapt from there. This is all covered in the WWDC video.

Comment: Thanks Rop for your quick reply. I will surely watch WWDC Video.